# Thai Language Maxent Model Generation

Tags: nlp, opennlp

While creating models using ApacheOpenNlp for languages such as Thai, is it good to tokenize and use the tokenized corpus to train the MxentModel, or the untokenized sentences should be used.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should tokenize both your training corpus and, during runtime, your sentences.

If you have a Name Finder training corpus for example, it is easy to train a tokenizer using the same corpus. From command line you can run

```
sh bin/opennlp TokenizerTrainer.namefinder
```

and it will train the tokenizer from the namefinder corpus.

**Update:**
This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43687295/877102) explains how to use the old Thai models.