# OpenNLP POSTagger output from command line

Tags: nlp, opennlp

I want to use [OpenNLP](http://opennlp.apache.org/cgi-bin/download.cgi) in order to tokenize Thai words. I downloaded OpenNLP and [Thai tokenize model](http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/models/thai/?C=M;O=A) and run the following

```
./bin/opennlp POSTagger -lang th -model thai.tok.bin < sentence.txt > output.txt
```

I put `thai.tok.bin` that I downloaded on the directory that I call from and run the following. `sentence.txt` has this text inside `กินอะไรยังนาย`. However, the output I got has only these text:

```
Usage: opennlp POSTagger model < sentences
Execution time: 0.000 seconds
```

I'm pretty new to `OpenNLP`, please let me know if anyone knows how to get output from it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The models from your [link](http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/models/thai/?C=M;O=A) are outdated. First you need some manual steps to convert the model.

1. Download the file [thai.tok.bin.gz](http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/models/thai/tokenize/thai.tok.bin.gz) and extract to an empty folder. Rename the extracted file `thai.tok.bin` to `token.model`
2. In the same folder, create a file named `manifest.properties` with the following contents:

   ```
   Manifest-Version=1.0.  
   Language=th  
   OpenNLP-Version=1.5.0  
   Component-Name=TokenizerME  
   useAlphaNumericOptimization=false
   ```
3. Now you can zip the files, if you are using Linux you can use this command: `zip thai.tok.bin token.model manifest.properties`
4. Try your model:

   ```
   sh bin/opennlp TokenizerME ~/Downloads/thai-token.bin/thai.tok.bin <  thai_sentence.txt



   Loading Tokenizer model ... done (0,097s)     
   กินอะไร ยังนาย     


   Average: 333,3 sent/s      
   Total: 1 sent     
   Runtime: 0.003s     
   Execution time: 0,108 seconds
   ```

Now that you have the updated tokenizer, you can do similar with the POS Tagger model.

1. Download the file [thai.tag.bin.gz](http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/models/thai/postag/thai.tag.bin.gz) and extract to a empty folder. Rename the extracted file `thai.tag.bin` to `pos.model`
2. In the same folder, create a file named `manifest.properties` with the following contents:

   ```
   Manifest-Version=1.0
   Language=th
   OpenNLP-Version=1.5.0
   Component-Name=POSTaggerME
   ```
3. Now you can zip the files, if you are using Linux you can use this command: `zip thai.pos.bin pos.model manifest.properties`

Finally, we can try the two models combined:

```
sh bin/opennlp TokenizerME ~/Downloads/thai-token.bin/thai.tok.bin < thai_sentence.txt > thai_tokens.txt
sh bin/opennlp POSTagger ~/Downloads/pt-pos-maxent/thai.pos.bin < thai_tokens.txt
```

The result is:

```
กินอะไร_VACT ยังนาย_NCMN
```

Please, let me know if this is the expected result.

Comment: This is great and very helpful! Thanks @wcolen! I tried `thai.tok.bin` and it worked. I suppose the `pos.model` will work too.