# OpenNLP gives error when using Thai model

Tags: java, nlp, opennlp, thai

I have tried to follow the advice from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43687295/355715), but I got this error:

```
C:\OpenNLP_models\tool\apache-opennlp-1.5.3-bin\apache-opennlp-1.5.3\bin>opennlp TokenizerME C:\OpenNLP_models\tool\apache-opennlp-1.5.3-bin\apache-opennlp-1.5.3\bin\thai.tok.bin < test.txt

Loading Tokenizer model ... Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at opennlp.tools.util.model.BaseModel.getManifestProperty(BaseModel.java:491)
    at opennlp.tools.util.model.BaseModel.initializeFactory(BaseModel.java:245)
    at opennlp.tools.util.model.BaseModel.loadModel(BaseModel.java:237)
    at opennlp.tools.util.model.BaseModel.<init>(BaseModel.java:181)
    at opennlp.tools.tokenize.TokenizerModel.<init>(TokenizerModel.java:125)
    at opennlp.tools.cmdline.tokenizer.TokenizerModelLoader.loadModel(TokenizerModelLoader.java:39)
    at opennlp.tools.cmdline.tokenizer.TokenizerModelLoader.loadModel(TokenizerModelLoader.java:31)
    at opennlp.tools.cmdline.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:62)
    at opennlp.tools.cmdline.tokenizer.TokenizerMETool.run(TokenizerMETool.java:41)
    at opennlp.tools.cmdline.CLI.main(CLI.java:225)
```

The `test.txt` file contains the sentence "ผมหิวข้าว".

Could anyone tell me how to fix it? I want to use the POSTagger.
Thank you.

Comment: Please copy-paste your error message, don't post it as a screenshot...

Comment: Sorry for doing that. I just edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're missing the `manifest.properties` file. Can you unzip the `thai.tok.bin` file and check that it contains these files:

1. `token.model` (binary tokenizer model)
2. `manifest.properties` (configuration)

Contents of `manifest.properties` should be like this, taken from the question you link to:

```
Manifest-Version=1.0.
Language=th
OpenNLP-Version=1.5.0
Component-Name=TokenizerME
useAlphaNumericOptimization=false
```

Comment: My manifest.properties file is as you posted , but I got the same error.

Comment: Sorry, no idea then.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. Your solution is practical, but I defined the wrong file's extension of manifest.properties.Thank you.

Comment: Can I ask you some more question? I got a new problem which is that the result seem not to be encode as utf-8 "à¸?à¸´à¸™à¸­à¸°à¹„à¸£à¸¢à¸±à¸‡à¸™à¸²à¸¢" . Do you know how I can fix it.

Comment: Sounds like a locale problem. What is the value of LANG and LC_ALL if you type `locale`? (Also, are you using Cygwin? I don't know much about Windows...)

Comment: I cannot type LANG, LC_ALL on command window and I did not use Cygwin. My solution now is to run on Eclipse. Thank for your attention and sorry for replying very late.